# Responsive Image Replacement

Tags: html, image, web, responsive-design

I am building a responsive site through wordpress and want to display 3 separate images across 4 screen sizes, the images are banner ads.

With the theme I am using I am adding the code to the widget to specify each separate div and image. As I am new to the responsive way of designing I have an issue which I am unsure of the ideal workaround.

The css specifies each size @media which is working fine but my method of specifying display none to the div I want to show and not show is not working as it is being overidden by the base style.

IIs it possible to specify which image is shown per media size by placing code in the image src element? i.e

Sorry if this is a bit indecipherable but if anybody has an incling what I am on about and knows the best way to show responsive images and replacement images that would be great.

Comment: This might be interesting for you: http://24ways.org/2011/adaptive-images-for-responsive-designs-again

Comment: Another resource you might find useful: http://responsejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could assign each image a unique id or use a class name and within your media query use `display:none;`

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
  img.myImage{
  display: none;
 }
}
```